Embeded PDF is blocked by Chrome
I have a problem with an embedded PDF file in Joomla. It worked just fine until today when I tried to change the PDF content. I guess everything started when I updated to the latest Joomla version, but I can't confirm that for sure because it worked before update.
I usually do this with inserting CMS content -> media in "article" and then choosing the file and embedding it. I also tried with object tag, embed tag and nothing worked, still the same "blocked by Chrome" error.
Is there an issue with iframe? Any tips that you guys have is more than welcome! Thank you in advance!

Not really sure, but maybe you could check pages with embedded pdfs that you created prior to the upgrade and see if they still work. If they do, compare them to the newly created pages that don't work using web developer tools in your browser (usually CTRL SHIFT i). Then, you might be able to see what is causing the issue. Assuming you found what was wrong, you could then try editing the broken pdf article by setting the editor to none and directly editing the html.

I have the exact same problem - no solution found yet! Help

I still use iframe to embed pdf's and don't have a problem.  What version of Joomla & what editor are you using?

If using version J5.1.2 and TinyMCE editor, there is a new setting that needs to be switched off called Sandbox Iframes.  This is a new security feature in an effort to control what can be displayed in the iframe.

